# Recover a PDF on iOS from a web service

Tags: ios, web-services, pdf-generation, reportviewer

I have a strange problem with my iOS application that calls a .NET web service to recover a PDF.

- The web service does some stuff, and returns a PDF document as a reference of the web service (via an **out parameter**)
- The iOS application call the web service, receives an answer and deals with the XML received.

To begin, the web service just returned a "simple" pdf (created in Word). I test my application and all was running well.

I was happy :). Then, I used Microsoft Report Viewer to really generate the PDF...

So I really implement my web service for create the PDF with ReportViewer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671(v=vs.80).aspx). The pdf generated was correct, I can open it on my server when it was generated. But when I receive the answer in the iOS application, I can't open it because it was **corrupt**.

Here is the difference of the XML I receive from the web service :

- When I return the pdf generated with Word : http://pastie.org/7982815
- When I return the pdf generated with ReportViewer : http://pastie.org/7982811

So the main difference is the image parameter that is **one-part** with the simple PDF and **split** with the ReportViewer PDF.

Actually I have no idea why the byte array is split as it, and I don't know what I could do to receive a valid PDF.

Once again, the PDF generated with ReportViewer is good, I can open it on the server, and when I send it by e-mail I can open it on my iPad. The problem comes when the web service returns me the PDF as a byte array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "split" image is actually an artifact of the web service trying to parse the image for line separators (ie 0d0a == carriage return / new line). If you're lucky, you can reassemble the image by taking each one of the records, including the 0d0a, and just concatenating them. This may be easier than fixing the real problem, which is that your web service is not sending you a single blob, but trying to parse an image into "lines".

Comment: Thank you for these informations ! I will try to reassemble the image. One more question: Why these line separators (0d0a) appears when the PDF is generated? For now it is a simple PDF with just a text on a blank page.

Comment: Whoever wrote your web service could tell. Perhaps the file that is passed does not have a .pdf suffix? All I can tell you is that since you can see the line separators on their own line, the only conclusion one could make is that the service is trying to send you what it thinks are lines of text, each line in its own "block".

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, I solved my problem by concat all the data contains in the **image** array.

So, considering the XML I receive from the web service (http://pastie.org/7982811), here is my objective-c code to build the correct NSData (the pdf) :

```
NSMutableData *concatData = [NSMutableData data];
NSArray *partsData = [result objectForKey:@"image"];

for(NSDictionary *dicPdfDataLine in partsData) {            // Foreach parts of data
    NSArray *arrayPdfDataLine = [dicPdfDataLine allValues];
    NSData *dataLine = [arrayPdfDataLine objectAtIndex:0];  // Get the NSData of the current part part
    [concatData appendData:dataLine];                       // Concat the data
}
```